# is there an way to implement installment plan using stripe in laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I am working on online payment using laravel and  stripe i have implemented stripe for normal payment but i also want to implement installment plan, i am new to implement this installment plan.

is there any way to do that

```
$token =   \Stripe\Token::create([
  'card' => [
    'number' => $request->card_number,//'5555 5555 5555 4444',
    'exp_month' => $request->expire,
    'exp_year' => $request->year,
    'cvc' => $request->code,
  ],
]);

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  'amount' => $request->price,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'description' =>$request->repair,
  'source' => $token,
  'payment_method_options' => [
        'card' => [
            'installments' => [
                'enabled' => true
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

i have added this payment method option but no success

Answer (score 0):

Official support for installment plans [1] are only available for Stripe Accounts in Mexico as of this writing, so you'll want to ensure that's true. If not, you'll need another solution. These use the newer PaymentIntent object for collecting payment (rather than the older Charge object).

I would recommend refactoring from using Tokens to use the newer PaymentMethod model. Furthermore, it's recommended for PCI compliance reasons to tokenize card details on the client with Stripe.js, so you'll likely want to use stripe.createPaymentMethod on the client and use the ID returned from that payment flow to then pass the payment_method_id to your server to ultimately create the PaymentIntent.

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'payment_method' => $json_obj->payment_method_id,
    'amount' => 3099,
    'currency' => 'mxn',
    'payment_method_options' => [
        'card' => [
            'installments' => [
                'enabled' => true
            ]
        ]
    ],
]);
```

In case you're not based in Mexico, other options include implementing the installment logic by hand in your own application, or using SubscriptionSchedules [2]. For SubscriptionSchedules, you would create the schedule with a `cancel` `end_behavior` where each of the phases represents an installment.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/installments 
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules 
[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/create#create_subscription_schedule-end_behavior

Comment: PaymentIntent it give me erorr like controller not found is it not stripe function?

Comment: You may need a newer version of stripe-php [1] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php

Comment: Which version are you using now? The latest is 7.27.1

Comment: is it due to version new version will give this option?

Comment: You'll want to check to make sure you have at least the PaymentIntent class in your version of Stripe-php.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's docs now seems to have a bit more documentation on how to achieve this:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#installment-plans

Essentially you create a one-time-use Price object, then use it to create a SubscriptionScheduler object. It looks like you already need a Customer, presumably with a stored payment method.